# Why does the PartialView keep calling itself?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I've tried to set up a small demo, in which an article has multiple comments. The article details view, should render the comments in a partial view. The partialView itself contains another partial view for adding a new comment.

When I try to add another comment I receive a `InsufficientExecutionStackException`, because the action in the controller keeps calling itself. Why does this happen?

(If somebody has the course material at hand. A similar example should be at module 9 in the 70-486 course from Msft; that's what I trying to build.)

**Edit:** The full code is on [github](https://github.com/Servellia/Mod9_ajax)

**Edit2:** The sample on Github has been fixed. As Stephen Muecke pointed out, the fact, that both the `GET` and `POST` method hat the same names was causing the circular reference. 
Before any more people point out, that DI and View Models are missing and that re-rendering all comments is sub-optimal: Yes I am aware and no, those things were nothing, that I wanted to accomplish. This was just a quick n dirty demo.

Controller:

```
[ChildActionOnly]
public PartialViewResult _GetCommentsForArticle(int articleId)
{
    ViewBag.ArticleId = articleId;
    var comments = db.Comments.Where(x => x.Article.ArticleId == articleId).ToList();
    return PartialView("_GetCommentsForArticle", comments);
}


public PartialViewResult _CreateCommentForArticle(int articleId)
{
    ViewBag.ArticleId = articleId;
    return PartialView("_CreateCommentForArticle");
}

[HttpPost]
public PartialViewResult _CreateCommentForArticle(Comment comment, int articleId)
{
    ViewBag.ArticleId = articleId;
    comment.Created = DateTime.Now;
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Comments.Add(comment);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
    var comments = db.Comments.Where(x => x.Article.ArticleId == articleId).ToList();
    return PartialView("_GetCommentsForArticle", comments);
}
```

relevant line in the Details.cshtml for Article:

```
@Html.Action("_GetCommentsForArticle", "Comments", new { articleId = Model.ArticleId})
```

_GetCommentsForArticle:

```
@model IEnumerable<Mod9_Ajax.Models.Comment>
<div id="all-comments">
    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Text)
            </th>
        </tr>

        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
           @* ... *@
        }
    </table>
</div>
@Html.Action("_CreateCommentForArticle", "Comments", new { articleId = ViewBag.ArticleId })
```

_CreateCommentForArticle:

```
@model Mod9_Ajax.Models.Comment
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("_CreateCommentForArticle", "Comments", new AjaxOptions
{
    HttpMethod = "POST",
    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
    UpdateTargetId = "all-comments"
}))
{
    @* ... *@

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Comment: As an aside, if the training material is instructing you to use an Entity Model class as a ViewModel or DTO then I should tell you it's bad practice - always use a dedicated ViewModel/DTO type instead of re-using Entity Model types.

Comment: I just replicated your views in a new empty project with a simple `CommentsController::Details` action and I cannot reproduce this issue. Can you post your entire project in a Zip/archive somewhere?

Comment: Why does you POST method return all comments when you already have them in the view (as opposed to just appending the new comment to the view)

Comment: @StephenMuecke In theory: add the new comment; fetch all comments; replace the existing comments with the new payload. 
Dai: In this case I do not care about vms, DI, repositories or any other good practice. Just want to get it done.

Comment: Seems unnecessary to re-render all the existing comments again, but I agree with @Dai - the code you have shown is not causing _the action in the controller keeps calling itself_ - its something else you have not shown us.

Comment: Just pushed to code Github: https://github.com/Servellia/Mod9_ajax.
@StephenMuecke There is not much else to it, or I am missing it every time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To explain what is happening, you have a form that posts to you `_CreateCommentForArticle()` method, which then renders your `_GetCommentsForArticle.cshtml` partial which in turn includes `@Html.Action("_CreateCommentForArticle", ...)`.

In the initial GET method for `Details()` the view will be rendered correctly, but when you submit the form, the current request for the `_GetCommentsForArticle` page is a `[HttpPost]` method, so `@Html.Action()` will look for a `[HttpPost]` method (not the `[HttpGet]` method). That `[HttpPost]` in turn renders the `_GetCommentsForArticle.cshtml` partial and again calls the `_CreateCommentForArticle()` POST method which renders the `_GetCommentsForArticle.cshtml` partial and so on until you run out of memory and the exception is thrown.

You can solve this by changing the name of the POST method, for example

```
[HttpPost]
public PartialViewResult Create(Comment comment, int articleId)
```

and modify the form to suit

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Create", "Comments", new AjaxOptions { ...
```

Comment: I was just sitting in the lab and came to the same conclusion. This is excactly what was failing. Once I decorated the action with `[HttpPost, ActionName("_PostCreate")]` and amended the `Ajax.BeginForm` it did begin to work.

Comment: There is a lot of unnecessary code in you app and you degrading performance by making at least 2 unnecessary database calls. When I get a chance I'll update the answer with some further comments.

Comment: I am fully aware of all (well, most) shortcomings. I was scratching my head about the circular reference. The code was the default mvc template from visual studio and then just added the models and the DAL to demonstrate my point. (And this is really how the 70-486 course demonstrates Ajax. Just double checked)