# mvc c#, Custom attribute causes infinite loop when posting with error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, custom-attribute

I have this custom attribute:

```
public class CountAttribute : ValidationAttribute
    {
        public string Number1 { get; set; }
        public string Number2 { get; set; }

        public CountAttribute()
        {

        }

        public CountAttribute(string ErrorMessage, string Number1, string Number2)
        {
            this.Number1 = Number1;
            this.Number2 = Number2;
            this.ErrorMessage = ErrorMessage;
        }

        protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
        {
            var propertyNumber1 = validationContext.ObjectType.GetProperty(Number1);
            int number1 = (int)propertyNumber1.GetValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance);
            var propertyNumber2 = validationContext.ObjectType.GetProperty(Number2);
            int number2 = (int)propertyNumber2.GetValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance);
            if (number1 + number2 != (int)value)
            {
                return new ValidationResult(ErrorMessage);
            }
            return ValidationResult.Success;
        }
    }
```

And on the layout I have modal window rendered action like this (which going to crash with infinite loop):

```
<div id="loginBox" class="modal-z">
    @{ Html.RenderAction("Login", "Account"); }
</div>
```

Form post works just fine when custom attribute is commented or model is valid.

When I post form with errors it redisplays the model correctly, but when I post it again (valid or invalid), it is stacked in loop. Writes this error on the RenderAction (login):

> Insufficient stack to continue executing the program safely. This can
>   happen from having too many functions on the call stack or function on
>   the stack using too much stack space.

How to fix this?

**EDIT:**

```
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public PartialViewResult Login(string returnUrl)
        {
            ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
            return PartialView();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return PartialView(model);
            }
            var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);

            switch (result)
            {
                case SignInStatus.Success:
                   // some redirect logic
                default:
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login.");
                    return PartialView(model);
            }
        }
```

Comment: It has nothing to do with you validation attribute. Post your controller methods (it may possibly be as per [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40771972/why-does-the-partialview-keep-calling-itself/40781291#40781291))

Comment: Yes, i agree with you that doesn't make any sense, but if there is no custom attribute, it works just fine on every POST of the application. I can try to rename it.

Comment: I renamed it and problem still occurs. But it occurs only when the validation failed for the custom attribute, other attributes works correctly.

Comment: It works fine because `ModelState` is valid and you do not return the view - again, it has nothing to do with your attribute (temporarily turn off client side validation and enter invalid values in other controls so the view is returned and the same thing will occur)

Comment: That is true, but I don't understand, why some actions works good even with disable client validation and other don't.